# Is there any substantial difference if I sell my computer after warranty expiration?

Tags: selling, extended-warranty

I’m planning to sell a notebook computer. The warranty is going to expire soon. It has been extended once and cannot be extended again.

Because I don’t want to take the risk of high repair costs after warranty expiration, I decided to sell it. Since I have been getting busy recently, I am not going to sell it until the warranty expires.

Now, I’m worrying that whether the value of my notebook computer decreases significantly after the expiration. In other words, I want to ask whether it is normal for a warranty which ends in a week worths a lot.

The warranty is an official one (actually the notebook computer is a MacBook Air and the warranty is AppleCare). Not sure if that matters though.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to check the small-print of the warranty: I'm pretty sure I've seen some warranties that are (or at least claim to be) not transferable from the original purchaser, so it may not make any real difference whether it's expired or not.

Comment: I did ask the staff in Genius Bar, and they said that the warranty is transferable. Also, I wasn’t asked for providing my personal information in my previous repairs, so I assume that they won’t check the name of the owner anyway.

Comment: Here's a tip: don't buy insurance, especially on consumer goods.

Answer (score 3):

It will not make a difference, if the warranty is even transferable at all. A warranty that's about to expire isn't very valuable. The used computer market is quite inefficient, so I think when you actually attempt to sell the computer you will find that arbitrary variation in what buyers are willing to pay is much larger than the effect of the warranty.

Comment: Even 5 year old MacBook Pros retain quite a health resale value.